# Single power supply for LF353N opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I only have one power supply and I only have the LF353N opamp. Is it possible to design a non-inverting amplifier circuit for this op-amp with only a single power supply?

Otherwise, what are some single power supply op-amp alternatives could I use? I'm using a non-inverting amplifier to amplify a 1V pk-pk 10kHz sine wave to 5V pk-pk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Op-amps are not inherently single or dual supply orientated. OK there may be a tiny majority of exceptions that have a "ground" or "0 volt" pin but the vast majority have a positive power pin, a negative power pin, 2 inputs and an output.

The rules are simple: -

- Supply enough power voltage differential to exceed the lower power limit voltage
- Don't supply more than the maximum power rail
- Keep inputs within the upper and lower power rail as dictated by the "input common mode voltage range" in the data sheet
- Don't expect the output to swing to or beyond either power rail

So, the LF353A expects to be run from a power rail differential greater than 10 volts and less than 36 volts. If you want to call that +/- 5 volts and +/- 18 volts that's up to you.

The typical input common mode voltage range is typically -12 volts to +15 volts (on a +/- 15 volt supply) and this translates to +3 volts to +30 volts on a single ended +30 volt supply

OR

+3 volts to +20 volts on a single +20 volt supply.

However, the data sheet only guarantees +/- 11 volts on a +/- 15 volt supply so if you don't want to take risks this translates to +4 volts to + 26 volts on a single +30 volt supply.

There are graphs in the data sheet that give more detail such as figure 6 and 7.

There are also specifications and graphs for output voltage swing.

In short >99% of all op-amps do not understand there power supply regime - they are only interested in the differential supply voltage being within workable limits.

Comment: I think the only problem with me just sticking in say for an example 0V and 12V into the power rails is that my signal will be clipped at the trough. I will have to DC bias my signal in order to see the whole signal.

Comment: @GuyLee yes, if your input signal sits around 0 volts then you need to bias it up or use split rails.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible but you will need a low impedance voltage at mid supply.  Voltage reference or buffered voltage divider depending on your DC specifications.